# Pandas grouping and inverting df manipulating of hist.price data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stockquotes

For the following code the output returned is such:

[image]

The desired arrangement is however with the tickers raised and grouped/aggregated like:

[image]

All suggestions and feedback welcome.

*Code sample*

```
def prepare_data(symbol, look_back_period):
    start_date = date.today() - timedelta(days=look_back_period)
    end_date = date.today()

    prices_df = get_symbol_prices(symbol=symbol, start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)
    prices_df = prices_df[['close']]

    df = pd.DataFrame(prices_df)
    df.index.name = 'datetime'
    df['symbol'] = symbol
    return df


def get_final_df(tickers, look_back_period):
    df = pd.DataFrame()

    for symbol in symbol_list:
        df = df.append(prepare_data(symbol=symbol, look_back_period=look_back_period))
    return df


def main():

    historical_df = get_final_df(tickers=TICKERS, look_back_period=LOOK_BACK_PERIOD)
    output_folder = 'E:/'
    file_name = 'HISTORICALPORTFOLIO.csv'
    historical_df.to_csv(os.path.join(output_folder, file_name))
```

Comment: Try `pd. pivot_table`.

Comment: do you need the multiindex where `'close'` is over all columns?

Comment: I've tried pivot and it's a little too unspecific, i.e. doesn't group tickers. [multi-index isn't critical and actually probably unwanted for further aggregating]

Comment: see my answer. isn't that exactly what you are searching for ? or what do you mean with 'unspecific'

Comment: pivot_table solved my issue in conjunction with rename_axis as provided in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pivoted df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'datetime': ['2022-06-08', '2022-06-09', '2022-06-10', '2022-06-08', '2022-06-09', '2022-06-10', '2022-06-08', '2022-06-09', '2022-06-10', '2022-06-08', '2022-06-09', '2022-06-10', '2022-06-08', '2022-06-09', '2022-06-10'], 
    'value': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 
    'name': ['AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'ABNB', 'ABNB', 'ABNB', 'ADBE', 'ADBE', 'ADBE', 'AMD', 'AMD', 'AMD', 'AMZN', 'AMZN', 'AMZN']})

#if 'datetime' is your index, just add this before pivoting:
df = df.reset_index()

res = df.pivot(index='datetime', columns='name', values='value').reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)

print(res)

     datetime  AAPL  ABNB  ADBE  AMD  AMZN
0  2022-06-08     0     3     6    9    12
1  2022-06-09     1     4     7   10    13
2  2022-06-10     2     5     8   11    14
```

Comment: For "res = df.pivot(index='datetime', columns='symbol', values='close').reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)" that is placed after "get_final_df" in main(), there is following Key Error... "in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'datetime'"

Comment: see my input dataframe and how I named the columns. You need to adjust the column names to the data you have

Comment: Yes that is ‘’datetime,’ ‘symbol’ and ‘close’ respectively.

Comment: Ok, hm. Is 'datetime' maybe your index and not a column ?

Comment: I believe so, yes.

Comment: updated my answer. Just add `df=df.reset_index()` before pivoting.